# Java Try/Catch decorator for void functions

Tags: java, spring, api, exception, try-catch

I am building an API service and a lot of the methods have nothing to return but I want to be able to return a status message to the caller to let them know we are done all though all my front end changes to an action are optimistic, sometime we might have to revert based on some CRUD failing. The obvious fix here would be to have a try catch in these methods and send appropriate messages back to the client.

What I was wondering is if there was a way that I could write a generic try/catch block and be able to attach it to all method calls. I used to do this in python using decorators. I don't want to explicitly have the try catch in each method if that makes sense. Is there a way to do this in Java? I am using Spring MVC, so maybe that has some features for this? I wasn't really sure of what to search on google for and wasn't getting any relevant results.

Comment: Spring supports a basic level of aspect oriented programming (see Spring-AOP), so you could wrap an aspect that does the exception catching around your methods. Exception handling in Java is a classic use for AOP. But of course, this will not change the return type. So if your method does not declare that it returns something, your aspect will also not be able to return something suddenly. You can throw exceptions, of course.

Comment: As Spring supports AOP( Aspect Oriented PRogramming) you can use logging aspect of it. It means at a given point cut you can put a message in your logs. Below is alink with more information about it. I have implemented it for before and after point cuts http://www.journaldev.com/2583/spring-aop-example-tutorial-aspect-advice-pointcut-joinpoint-annotations-xml-configuration

Answer (score 0):

This below thing is generic to Java and not covering Spring.

From all method calls, you can define to say it throws the generic "Exception" as below

```
 public void writeList() throws Exception {
```

So that in the main function, you can capture using a try block and log it.

Comment: Yeah sure but there are multiple api endpoints that I will be exposing and I don't want a try/catch for each of the endpoint mappings.